# How do i fix the "Stopping all processes with SIGTERM" in discord.py bots in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

so i am hosting my discord bot in heroku for free (ik it's not good but i can't offer to pay money rn)
so yesterday my bot was working as good as ever and when i woke up today i got an approved message from Discord bot list and after that my bot started going online and offline continuously so i restarted all dynos and i got this in the logs

```
Restarting
2020-07-19T15:48:44.371670+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-07-19T15:48:45.296606+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-19T15:48:45.677248+00:00 app[worker.1]: sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
2020-07-19T15:48:46.013782+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-19T15:48:49.175960+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python Yam-Yam.py`
2020-07-19T15:48:49.836878+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-19T15:53:23.090024+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2020-07-19T15:53:23.103443+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-07-19T15:53:24.363803+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

can you please tell me why did this happen and how to fix it

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Instances running on the free tier of Heroku get terminated after a period of inactivity.

Comment: 1st my code is long and many
2nd i remember the bot went offline after its free trail ended but it didn't do as this one and the bot wasn't inactive it was working in 16 servers with log channels and stuff

Comment: Bro your heroku dyno might be finished.